# Pip can't install any package

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Hello approximately about 2 weeks ago I started not being able to download python packages or even access the pypi website which is "unreachable" on chrome and firefox.

When I try to download a package it gives me this :

```
$ python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/numpy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I didn't change anything on my computer, it just started to do this one day and on both my computers, I don't understand.
Does anybody have any idea why this is happening ? I searched for hours but couldn't find anything to correct this bug.

What I have attempted : 
- uninstall every python program and reinstall
- check my drivers (you never know)
- deactivate any proxy
- disable my firewall

OS : Windows 10

Comment: What OS are you using ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot, just edited

Comment: Why do you use python -m pip install, instead of using pip directly ? When you are installing python on windows OS, there should be an options to install extra packages. Select that option, also select the option that says something like : "export environment variables". Finally you should be able to simply run "pip install some_lib" on cmd. Try that and see what happens.

Comment: It doesn't change anything I would normally use pip install but I used this because it is the command they say to use on the numpy website

Comment: It gives the same error anyway

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Retry+after+connection+broken+by+ProtocolError+Connection+aborted+ConnectionResetError+An+existing+connection+was+forcibly+closed

Comment: It's either SSL error or firewall problem. Or both.

Comment: Also the problem is not only with pip by I can't access it from chrom nor firefox so my guessing is that it's not a problem with python

Comment: Tried disabling firewall, no change

Comment: Don't really knwo what to do as for the ssl error ? this is something i am not aware of

Comment: I faced this same issue today, as it turns out company vpn connection was screwing up the connection to the mirrors. Restarting the system and disconnecting from the proxy worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So for anybody searching for a solution, I found this which might not be optimal but at least it works, instead of `pip install package` use this command

`python.exe -m pip install package --proxy="proxy:port"`

You can find a big list of free proxies here : https://free-proxy-list.net/ (note that not all of them work and you might wanna try multiple before getting one that works)

So for example you could use :
`python.exe -m pip install numpy --proxy="179.185.199.195:8080"`

Comment: This worked for me, but you can use the actual company proxy address found in the Windows proxy settings. Pip is trying to connect directly without going through the proxy, causing the firewall to slap it down.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue due to the SSLKEYLOGFILE environmental variable in windows (used for tls decryption) if set to an invalid path also causes this error in python where other software will ignore the missing file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @MrTeriyaki you are actually a life saver. I searched for maybe 2-3 hours trying to solve this problem. Seemingly my entire pip just stopped working one day. Totally forgot that I added the SSLKEYLOGFILE variable and forgot to delete it after. I literally fully reinstalled everything python related on my computer, and I don't think I would have solved it without finding this comment.

Answer (score 2):

Using proxy from the previous answer will temporarily make things work - if you find a proxy that doesn't timeout, but it's not fixing the problem and using proxy will hamper your download speeds in most cases.

What I've found is that you need to investigate your Python interpreter location and make sure the venv is not causing problems.

For instance, if setuptools won't update then most likely there is already a part of your code or project that is continually using setuptools - prohibiting it from updating - and other packages need new versions of setuptools to install.

For some reason this then causes "ConnectionResetError: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" to occur for most packages like tensorflow, keras, pandas etc.

Recreating your venv in another empty location will reset any packages

To do this in Pycharm:

```
File -> Settings
Project: -> Project Interpreter
Project Interpreter -> drop down list -> show all

Remove your current Python Interpreter location
Add New Environment
```

Then you will be asked to put in a location for your project:
Using a new location here will solve the [Win10054] ConnectionResetError for package installations.

Base Interpreter : point towards your python.exe location
( default usually : C:\Users\UserProfile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonXX\python.exe 
  and replace XX with your current version and UserProfile with your profile )

Most Important:
Because you've setup a new location, install setuptools first, if it's already installed, then upgrade it first.
After that you can migrate your code to the new venv and all new packages should work without any connectionResetErrors.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a problem with pip 20.3:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9190
I have downgraded to 20.2.4 and it worked for me.

(I know it cannot be the cause of the original problem, but I think this page is visited also by people currently experiencing the problem)

Answer (score 0):

In case problem persists behind a proxy, you may find [this solution](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9190#issuecomment-787783984) helps, like:

```
conn.tls_in_tls_required = False
at \Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this, It was installed automatically.

```
python.exe -m pip install upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary --proxy="proxy:port
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Windows is connected to a proxy or DNS that either does not work or for any reason disrupts the installation process of your desired package, go to the proxy or DNS section in the settings and delete the proxy or DNS and try again to install package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

This looks like a latest PIP issue. I have PIP v20 with python 3.7 work just fine.