# ReadTimeoutError/pip not installling any library

Tags: python, pip

as written in the title and as you can see in the first image I'm trying to install pandas and I get this error each time and not just pandas but all the libraries , I know this question has been asked but none of the answers that I found helped me .
I'm not using a proxy .

```
C:\Users\yoooo>pip install pandas
```

> C:\Users\yoooo>pip install pandas WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by
> 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
> Read timed out.  (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pandas/ WARNING:
> Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
> status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
> Read timed out.  (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pandas/ WARNING:
> Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
> status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
> Read timed out.  (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pandas/ WARNING:
> Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
> status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
> Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pandas/ WARNING:
> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
> status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
> Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pandas/
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas
> (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgtFv.png)

tried to ping pypi.org and got this

```
 C:\Users\yoooo>ping pypi.org
```

> Pinging pypi.org [2a04:4e42::223] with 32 bytes of data:
>
> Request timed out.
>
> Request timed out.
>
> Reply from 2a04:4e42::223: time=227ms
>
> Reply from 2a04:4e42::223: time=556ms
>
> Ping statistics for 2a04:4e42::223:
>
> Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 2, Lost = 2 (50% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
> Minimum = 227ms, Maximum = 556ms, Average = 391ms

[ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyGW5.png)

pip and python versions (I can't update pip obviously).

```
C:\Users\yoooo>python --version
```

> Python 3.8.6

`C:\Users\yoooo>pip --version`

> pip 20.2.1

[versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaO06.png)

what do you think the problem is ? and if it's caused by my internet provider what should I tell them ?
telling them I'm not able to install python libraries will not be understandable .
PS:

tried this and and it led to the same error eventually

```
C:\Users\yoooo>pip --default-timeout=1000 install pandas
```

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/ ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port)

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. It improves readability and easily copy-pastable

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sadly no , and even with 1000 seconds as timeout

Comment: @RocketNikita there is no code , just some commands 

the commands are as follows :

pip install pandas

ping pypi.org

python --version 

pip -- version

Comment: Well, select text in terminal and format it as code here.

Comment: not like this wait a few minutes I'll edit it for you

Comment: Does this one help?[Pip can't install any package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328655/pip-cant-install-any-package)

Comment: python.exe -m pip install numpy --proxy="179.185.199.195:8080" 

yep using this command actually helped :)) 

but is it safe ? what can I fix to undo this ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to give precedence to IPv4 over IPv6.

To do so, open CMD with administrator permissions and apply the following command:

```
netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::ffff:0:0/96 46 4
```

Comment: This was my problem but the command `netsh` is not available on my end.

Comment: @MaozZadok what did you end up using?

Comment: @Alex you can see my solution below "In my case, ubuntu 20.4, changing it to prefer IPv4 over IPV6, resolved the issue"

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the default timeout flag to pip:

```
pip --default-timeout=1000 install pandas
```

If that doesn't work, download the wheel file from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files). Then change directory to where you saved it. Then run:

```
pip install <.whl file name>
```

Comment: Have you installed any other libraries?

Comment: yep numpy , pyside 2,venv and more

Comment: Pandas is a large library. You might just have a slow internet connection. Try raising the default timeout.

Comment: I have a speed of ~160Mbs currently and I'm using an ethernet , so I don't think it's a slow connectivity problem .

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening then. I updated my answer to include details about how to install from wheel files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328655/pip-cant-install-any-package 

the first comment from this helped me , but I'm not sure that it is safe.

Yeah I think eventually I'll just manually download wheels or just use a free proxy

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't trust free proxies because there is a chance they can read the data passed through them. I recommend just manually installing the wheel.

Comment: I tried using my IP instead of the random proxy (e.g. --proxy="my.personal.ip.ipv4:8080" )and It caused the same problem so it looks like my IP is causing the problem , I'll try contacting the internet provider and ask them to change my IP or something like that . if that doesn't work then I'll just have to download them manually .

Answer (score 1):

In my case, ubuntu 20.4, changing it to prefer IPv4 over IPV6, resolved the issue.

I was using `strace pip install <some packages>`, and noticed that IPv6 is been used (maybe there is a simple way).

this is how I change it to prefer IPv4 over IPV6:
edit the file `/etc/gai.conf` and uncomment the line:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

restart is not required.