# ConnectionResetError when attempting to install packages in Python

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, pycharm

I'm just beginning to learn python and am, struggling to get Python working correctly. I am using PyCharm as an IDE.

If you have any suggestions for debug techniques, or even an idea of what this error pertains to so I can research it myself that would be greatly appreciated.

I am getting the following error when attempting to install any packages:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Matt\PycharmProjects\pythonProject> pip install requests
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by 
the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by 
the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by 
the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by 
the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by 
the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/requests/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328655/pip-cant-install-any-package seems to have answers and workarounds.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server by any chance? Could be the case if this is a school/work computer or network

Comment: No Proxies, this is my personal computer at home.

I actually had no issues whatsoever on the installation I did on my work computer which does have a proxy haha, so I'm a tad confused

Comment: Thanks Matthias, yeah I had had a look over that particular thread before I posted.

I tried pedro's suggestion of just running "pip install numpy" in cmd, but I am met with the exact same sequence of error messages.

I've also tried turning off my firewall (Kaspersky), as well as Windows Firewall to no avail. 

In that thread they also mention installing "extra packages" when you install python?
I have tried reinstalling earlier but I don't recall ever encountering that dialogue,,,???


Thanks for the help so far!!!!